# what should be the hold type of return url to open in a new tab in sitecore?

Tags: c#, .net, popup, sitecore, sitecore6

i am using response.redirect to hold the url,which opens link on same page,
what can be other to open link in new tab?

```
public partial class DocumentLink : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField linkField = SitecoreItem.CurrentItem.Fields["DocumentLink"];
                Response.Redirect(GetUrl(linkField));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error(ex.ToString(), this);
            }
        }
    }

    public string GetUrl(Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField LinkField)
    {
        try
        {
            string url = "";
            switch (LinkField.LinkType)
            {
                case "internal":
                case "external":
                case "mailto":
                case "anchor":
                case "javascript":
                    url = LinkField.Url;
                    break;
                case "media":
                    MediaItem media = new MediaItem(LinkField.TargetItem);
                    url = Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/', MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(media));
                    break;
                case "":
                default:
                    break;
            }

            return url;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error(ex.ToString(), this);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute javascript code to open a new tab. This can be executed using the code:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(), 
    "newTab" + DateTime.Now.Ticks, 
    String.Format("<script>window.open('{0}');</script>", GetUrl(linkField)));
```

Here you can find some more information on adding client scripts dynamically http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178207.aspx.

Remember that browsers may block new windows.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the redirect? Do you not render a link to the document on the page?

If so I would just add a css class to the link and use some jQuery to make all those links open in a new window.

[Open a link in a new window using jQuery](http://befused.com/jquery/open-link-new-window)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.external-link').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open(this.href);
    });
});
```

Note, you can't force a link to open in a new tab, it depends on the users preference as to whether they want new windows to open in tabs or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sitecore's link webcontrol and pass field name to it, Sitecore will automatically render all attributes of your GenralLinkField

```
<sc:Link runat="server"  Field="DocumentLink">
```